# Codeigniter - Base URL not working within the <a href=""> tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry for this stupid question. I have searched for this question on stackoverflow but couldn't get an answer to my exact question.

Anyways.

This is my code:

```
$pid = $this->encrypt->encode($pid_info);
$data_user = array('first_name' => $first_name,
        'delete' => " <a href='base_url(profile/delete) . $pid'>Delete </a>");
```

But my URL is like `http://localhost/profile/view_note/base_url(delete)` instead of `http://localhost/profile/delete/$pid`

Any help is greatly appreciated. THanks.

Comment: I think you have to echo it. Try it.

Comment: How do I echo it inside quotes? Not letting me.

Comment: what do you have set as your base_url()?

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this:

```
 $pid = $this->encrypt->encode($pid_info);
 $data_user = array(
   'first_name' => $first_name,
   'delete' => '<a href="'.base_url().'/profile/delete/'. $pid'">Delete </a>"
 );
```

Comment: I agree. Probably no need forward slash before 'profile' since baseurl could finishing with forward slash. Or even to put URI into function like: `base_url('profile/delete/' . $pid)`